# How do I find out which crate dependency is requiring the standard library to be linked?

Tags: rust

I want to completely eliminate the dependency on `std` in my project so I disable the `std` feature in extern crates.

Somehow the final product is still linked to `std`, so I want to figure out which external crate is causing the linkage to `std`.

For standard shared libraries, this can be accomplished with `ldd`, but according to `file`, the `rlib` files in the deps directory are `ar` archives.

Comment: You will probably need to be more explicit. Individual crates aren't *linked* to anything. As `file` is telling you, a crate is closer to a bundle of object files. Only when the final product is built (executable, cdylib, etc) do all the crates get combined together and a final link step is performed.

Comment: You may want to try [cargo-nono](https://github.com/hobofan/cargo-nono) — it's rough yet but this is what it's for.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `cargo tree` to get a tree graph of all the dependencies and sub-dependencies of your project. Then you can find out which crate requires `std`, and potentially look for solutions/alternatives.